# User password change in jhipster application

Tags: jhipster, liquibase

I generated a standard jhipster application in java/angular 6. I changed the password from the interface. I do not remember them anymore.
I wanted to set them up in users.csv.
Since the password is hashed and salted I followed the following process:
1) Loaded the app locally 
2) Changed the password through the interface and noted it in clear in txt. I also tested the login with the new one and it worked
3) Retrieved the hashed one from the database
4) Copied the hashed password in users.csv

I did a mvnw and expected to be able to login with the new password since I though that the new version of users.csv would be taken into account.
The result was that I was able to connect neither as user/user not with the new one.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the liquibase changeset loading users.csv was run? if you changed only users.csv 
Liquibase has probably not detected any change as changeset has same checksum, so this changeset was not run again otherwise you would have got a checksum error.

To take your change into account, run `mvnw clean` to fully reset database assuming you're running H2 on disk as dev database.